# How to call dialogue boxes from multiple activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog

I have 3 dialogue boxes that I want to display in two different activities. What is the best way to have these dialogue boxes appear in both activities without copy and pasting the code (because that is bad!)? Below is roughly the scripts I use to make the dialogue boxes appear currently:

```
private void Box1(){
    new AlertDialog.Builder(Splash.this)
        .setTitle("title")
        .setMessage("dialogMessage")
        .setPositiveButton("Enter", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            finish();
        }
    }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            finish();
        }
    }).show();

}


private void Box2(){
    new AlertDialog.Builder(Splash.this)
    .setTitle("title")
    .setMessage("dialogMessage")
    .setPositiveButton("Enter", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                finish();
        }
    }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            finish();
        }
    }).show();

}

private void Box3(){
    new AlertDialog.Builder(Splash.this)
    .setTitle("title")
    .setMessage("message")
    .setPositiveButton("Try Again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                finish();
        }
    }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            finish();
        }
    }).show();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understant, this is not a question about Android activities, this is a question about code refactoring.
Why don't you create a new class, call it DialogCreator or DialogManager, and implement the dialog boxes in it?

Then you can write in the activity something like

```
new DialogCreator().showDialog("title", "message", "Try again");
```